# Understanding low rho values and high p-values from Spearman's rank test

Tags: p-value, spss, spearman-rho

I am looking for help regarding Spearman's Rank test results. I am trying to identify the correlation between 4 variables: age, gender, area (rural or urban) and education level. However, my results are showing weak rho values (-0.049, -0.113, 0.064) but have high p-values ranging from 0.293-0.993. Can anyone explain how to interpret this please? Do I say there are no strong correlations and so can continue to use variables together in regression analyses? Or do I have to say there is uncertainty and so they cannot be used together?

Here is my data table showing the correlation results.

Variable

```
              Gender    Age   Area    Education
```

Gender

```
Coefficient (ρ) 1.000   -0.049  0.064   -0.001
 
Significance (P)    -   0.550   0.552   0.993

Sample Size (N) 150 150 89  150
```

Age

```
 Coefficient (ρ)    -0.049  1.000   -0.113  0.061

Significance (P)    0.550   -   0.293   0.461

Sample Size (N) 150 150 89  150
```

Area

```
 Coefficient (ρ)    -0.064  -0.113  1.000   -0.011

Significance (P)    0.552   0.293   -   0.920

Sample Size (N) 89  89  89  89
```

Education

```
 Coefficient (ρ)    -0.001  0.061   -0.11   1.000

Significance (P)    0.993   0.461   0.920   -

Sample Size (N) 150 150 89  150
```

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: What is your research question ? Age, gender, area and education are all often included in a regression model, but unless we know what you are trying to achieve it is hard to advise.

Comment: A low correlation should go together with a high P-value, with nothing else said. In your case, I wouldn't think it especially helpful to use Spearman correlation with any binary variable (area and gender (presumably)). There may be some weak associations here but even if so something like chi-square tests might be a better start.

Comment: Sample values of Spearman's $r_S$ near $0$ indicate little or no correlation between the categorical; P-values above $0.05$ indicate no significant correlation at the 5% level.

Comment: These are $\binom{4}{2} = 6$ hypothesis tests on marginal correlations. It's generally a bad idea to carry out separate hypothesis tests and run the risk of inflated type-1 error rate in multiple comparisons. What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: Thank you for replying. My research question is trying to understand how demographical factors may influence people's likelihood of supporting rewilding. Therefore, I need to use a collinearity test to see whether age, gender, area and education are strongly correlated and thus might not be able to be analysed together. This was my output from SPSS when running all the variables together on Spearman test. I was told to use Spearman as I am testing education which is an ordinal variable. Am I right in assuming that these variables aren't strongly correlated and the high p-values support this?